# SwiftUI position and frame animation broken in iOS 14

Tags: swiftui, ios14, swiftui-animation

I have a progress view whose progress / width can be animated. This animation works by itself. However, in some cases, the parent view changes its layout and a new view is added above the progress bar. Then, the progress view moves down to make space for the new view. This is also animated. When both animations happen in iOS 13, the progress view moves down and the width of the blue progress bar is animated at the same time. In iOS 14, the progress view moves down but the blue progress bar also uses its animation to animate the position change. In iOS 13 it was only used for animating the width. This makes the animation look as if the progress bar flies into the progress view and it is wrong and looks weird.

[image]

I reproduced the code I have in my app with the following code. This code was also used to record the video.

```
struct MainView: View {
    @State var toggle = false
    @State var trim: CGFloat = 0.2

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Rectangle().frame(minHeight: 0, maxHeight: self.toggle ? 200 : 0)

            ProgressBarView(trim: self.$trim)

            Button(
                action: {
                    withAnimation {
                        self.toggle.toggle()
                        self.trim = self.toggle ? 0.8 : 0.2
                    }
                },
                label: {
                    Text("Toggle")
                })
        }
    }
}

struct ProgressBarView: View {
    @State var grow: Bool = false
    @Binding var trim: CGFloat

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            GeometryReader { geo in
                Rectangle()
                    .opacity(0.1)
                    .zIndex(0)

                Rectangle()
                    .frame(
                        minWidth: 0,
                        maxWidth: self.grow
                            ? geo.frame(in: .global).width * self.trim
                            : 0
                    )
                    .animation(Animation.easeOut(duration: 1.2).delay(0.5))
                    .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemBlue))
            }
        }
        .cornerRadius(10)
        .frame(height: 20)
        .onAppear(perform: {
            self.grow = true
        })
    }
}
```

**Update**

This is the original and working animation with the same code on my iPad that is still running iOS 13.7. I just removed the delay and increased the time to make the different animations more obvious.

[image]

**Update 2**

There was some confusion when answering the question so I copied some frames and put them into a screenshot. I hope this helps to understand my question. On the left is the animation on iOS 14 with the unwanted behavior. As you can see the blue progress bar doesn't appear in some images. In other images, it is only partly visible. On the right is the iOS 13 animation. The frames on the image (and all other frames) show the blue progress bar fully visible. It is always completely visible and on top of the background.

[image: Animation frame comparison]

I don't understand what change in iOS 14 (or maybe Swift 5.3 or whatever else) caused the animation to be different and I cannot find a workaround to this problem.

Answer (score 3):

[image: ProgressBarView]

Hey there! I made few changes in the `ProgressBarView` struct. Let's get to the less important changes first.

- Removed the `GeometryReader` and replaced it with `screen.width`. If you are using the bar inside a container in order to get the width of the container, use `GeometryReader`.
- Changed the Rectangle to a capsule.

To the important one

- I target the animation modifier of the bar to the Boolean variable that trigged the change of the progress bar, i.e. `grow`

```swift
struct ProgressBarView: View {
    @State var grow: Bool = false
    @Binding var trim: CGFloat
    
    let screen = UIScreen.main.bounds

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Capsule()
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black.opacity(0.1))
                
                Capsule()
                    .frame(width: self.grow ? screen.width * trim : 0)
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    .animation(Animation.easeOut(duration: 1).delay(0.5), value: self.grow)
            }
            .frame(width: screen.width, height: 20)
            .onAppear {
                self.grow = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1.1**

[image: ProgressBarView]

- I added an animation to the `ZStack` for the initial increase of bar from 0 to 0.2
- Changed the `DispatchQueue` delay to 0.18 sec.

The reason for the change in delay is because, since the expanding of the rectangle is changing the position of the bar in the y-direction, the animation effect with duration of 1.2 sec is being applied to the change in position which we don't want. Thus the delay of 0.18 starts the bar animation a bit after the expanding of the rectangle. This is a bit of a hack, but gets the work done. If I find a better solution, I'll update this answer with 'Update 2.0'. If you find a better solution, let me know.

**Code**

```swift
struct MainView: View {
    @State var toggle = false
    @State var trim: CGFloat = 0.2

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Rectangle().frame(minHeight: 0, maxHeight: self.toggle ? 200 : 0)

            ProgressBarView(trim: self.$trim)

            Button(
                action: {
                    withAnimation {
                        self.toggle.toggle()
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.18) {
                            self.trim = self.toggle ? 0.8 : 0.2
                        }
                    }
                },
                label: {
                    Text("Toggle")
                })
        }
    }
}

struct ProgressBarView: View {
    @State var grow: Bool = false
    @Binding var trim: CGFloat
    
    let screen = UIScreen.main.bounds

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Capsule()
                .opacity(0.1)
            
            Capsule()
                .frame(width: self.grow ? screen.width * trim : 0)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .animation(Animation.easeOut(duration: 1.2), value: self.trim)
        }
        .frame(width: screen.width, height: 20)
        .onAppear {
            self.grow = true
        }
        .animation(.easeOut(duration: 0.5), value: grow)
    }
}
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! In my app I use the ProgressView inside another view so that's why I used the `GeometryReader`. `self.grow` is only used for the first animation from 0 to the `trim`. You're basically removing the custom animation for when `trim` changes. But I want the `easeOut.delay` animation to work when `trim` changes. I updated my answer with the same code running on iOS 13.7 and the correct animation.

Comment: Hey @Yannick I have updated my answer. Have a look at it and let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks again for the update. The updated version is a lot closer to my original animation. However, there are still some frames where the blue progress bar is out of position. https://i.stack.imgur.com/rExUv.png

Comment: Hey @Praduyt, thank you for the update. The animation works if you don't change the state while the animation is in progress. For my app it works but I still consider it a workaround.
I'm still curious what changed in iOS 14 that causes this behavior.

Comment: Hey @Yannick I'm not sure what changed.